# ASP.NET 4, Entity Framework 4.2, IIS 7: Erratic behavior only fixed by restarting IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, iis-7, entity-framework-4

Using IIS 7, ASP.NET MVC 3, and EF 4.2, I load content from a database then send it to the client (nothing strange yet):

```
 var result = DB.Contacts.Select( p => new { id=p.ID, name=p.name }).ToList();
 return Json(result);
```

We tested it, approved it, and have it running at customers.  This is what it normally sends back:

```
"[{"id":1,"name":"one"},{"id":2,"name":"two"}]"
```

This is what it sends back when it's malfunctioning, which doesn't stop until we restart the IIS service (WWW):

```
"[{"id":null,"name":null},{"id":null,"name":null}]"
```

We haven't been able to recreate the issue on purpose, but once we were debugging in VS 2010 on Windows 7 and the debugger would step through code at random, jumping in a function from the 4th line to the first line, out of the function, back in the function, etc.

**What would cause this and how do you avoid it?**  We experience this on several different servers and workstations at several different customer locations.  For the most part, SQL Server 2008 or 2005 runs on the same machine as IIS 7.

Comment: In your anonymous object you are using the `text` property whereas in the JSON you have shown there is `name`. Is this a typo? Also is the `ID` property on your `Contact` object a nullable integer?

Comment: Are you creating a new Data context for each request?  Or are you sharing the context across multiple requests (using statics, global variables or singletons?)

Comment: the text and name were typos.  The ID isn't nullable ironically, yet all fields coming from the server were null.

Comment: What are the conditions that cause this to happen? Does it seem like a load related issue, or time dependent. If it's related to a period of time passing, I'd question the app pool recycling triggering some other issues. Also, do you have any exception handlers eating exceptions? MS DebugDiag tool is useful for monitoring IIS for exceptions that may otherwise go unnoticed:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798

Answer (score 2):

Jumping around in the debugger is something I've seen when:

- "Require source code to match" is disabled
- The debugger is using the wrong symbol (PDB) files
- The assembly was built in Release mode

One thing that I've found helpful is to open the "Modules" view in VS and make sure the PDB files for the assembly you are debugging is the correct one. The timestamp on the DLL should tell you if it's correct, or just knowing the path (depending on how you are debugging the site)

Without more context around the .NET code above, it's hard to say. Perhaps something is killing off your session... and the site isn't reinitializing stuff until you recycle the app pool or IIS.

Good luck!

*Edit: Some other ideas would be to hit the page/site with a load tester and place in some logging or an assertion immediately before the call to Json(..) that checks for null values in the anonymous object.. Sounds like an aging issue that creeps up after the app has been used for awhile. If that's the case, it may be reproducible with adequate load testing.*

Comment: I've ruled out just about everything, with the exception of AutoMapper 2.0 being used with Entity Framework, and possibly reusing a DB context for multiple users (only if a Controller is reused for multiple users.)  I couldn't imagine that an MVC 3 Controller object would be used for more than one user.